Using parameter pack on nested classes to declare a tuple
I'm trying to declare a tuple which types are based on types that are declared inside classes.
I'm trying the following code :
struct A
{
    using T = int;
};

struct B
{
    using T = float;
};

template <class ... Structs>
struct C
{
    std::tuple<(typename Structs::T), ...> t;
};

C<A,B> c;

But, I am getting an error operand of fold expression has no unexpanded parameter packs on the line where I am declaring the tuple, yet its declaration contains Structs which is unexpanded.
Am I missing something here?

No need to use a fold expression for parameter unpacking

It may be a little confusing. Fold expressions were added in C++17 and you are trying a fold over the comma operator, but the parameter pack expansion (which Jarod42 points out that you need here) has been around since C++11 and inserts a comma between each element - but not it's not the comma as in the comma operator but the other comma which is used in various comma-separated lists.

Syntax is without comma, i.e:
template <class ... Structs>
struct C
{
    std::tuple<typename Structs::T...> t;
};

